Faraday tensor index calculation
I have seen the following equality in a book about analytical electrodynamics:
$$\mathbf{\frac{\delta F^{\mu\nu}}{\delta A_{\rho}}F_{\mu\nu}+F^{\mu\nu}\frac{\delta F_{\mu\nu}}{\delta A_{\rho}}=2F^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\frac{\delta A_{\nu}}{\delta A_\rho}\cdot2}.$$
I'm wondering where the rightmost times-two factor came from. The left one comes from the fact that for any anti-symmetric tensor (specifically here, $F^{\mu\nu}$) $\, C^{\mu\nu}$, the following equation holds:
$$C^{\mu\nu}\delta F_{\mu\nu}=2C^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\delta A_\nu.$$
It seems the second times-two factor comes from an equality between both terms on the left side of the equation yet I have been unable to prove such equality. Can anyone help me?

One of the factors of two comes from the fact that there are two terms in the definition $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$.  So:
\begin{align*}
C^{\mu \nu} \delta F_{\mu \nu} &= C^{\mu \nu} ( \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu - \partial_\nu \delta A_\mu) \\ &= C^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu + C^{\nu \mu} \partial_\nu \delta A_\mu \\ &= C^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu + C^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu \\ &= 2 C^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu.
\end{align*}
The second step follows from the antisymmetry of $C^{\mu \nu}$ and the third step follows by relabeling indices in the second term.
The other factor of two comes from the fact that for any two tensors, $A_{\mu\nu} B^{\mu\nu} = B_{\mu\nu} A^{\mu\nu}$. This can most easily be seen by thinking about each side of this equation as a sum over all indices of products of tensor components, and noting that the order of the multiplicands in each term of the sum doesn't matter.
